# C pointer giving random value

Tags: c, pointers

I am teaching myself C for fun. I looked online for some practice programs, and found one where you take two input's: One with the amount of an imaginary product, and second the amount of money the imaginary customers gives you. Then you return the number of dollars bills, and change you would give to the customer.

This is the complete code which I wrote to solve this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float getDif(float c, float m)
{
    // First find the difference between
    // c & m (m - c = d)
    float dif = m - c;

    // Return the difference
    return dif;
}

void getChange(float dif, int* cash, float* change)
{
    // If difference is less than 0 we have a problem
    // because the customer gave us less money than
    // the cost of the product
    if(dif < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "The customer has not given enough money!...\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Cash is seen as the difference without any
    // decimals. So if the difference is $13.45
    // the cash would be 13 since cash is, in my
    // mind paper money
    *cash = (int) dif;

    // Change is seen as the difference - cash
    // if the difference is $13.45 the change
    // would be .45
    *change = dif - *cash;
}

void getCash(int cash, int* oneHundred, int* fifty, int* twenty, int* ten,
                int* five, int* one)
{
    if(cash == 0)
    {
        printf("Wow close to exact change! - No need for cash...\n");
        // End the function there is no need to continue
        return;
    }

    // Since cash is > 0 we need to determine the bills to return
    // to the user
    if(cash >= 100)
    {
        while(cash >= 100)
        {
            cash = cash - 100;
            (void) ++*oneHundred;
        }
    }

    if(cash >= 50)
    {
        while(cash >= 50)
        {
            cash = cash - 50;
            (void) ++*fifty;
        }
    }

    if(cash >= 20)
    {
        while(cash >= 20)
        {
            cash = cash - 20;
            (void) ++*twenty;
        }
    }

    if(cash >= 10)
    {
        while(cash >= 10)
        {
            cash = cash - 10;
            (void) ++*ten;
        }
    }

    if(cash >= 5)
    {
        while(cash >= 5)
        {
            cash = cash - 5;
            (void) ++*five;
        }
    }

    if(cash >= 1)
    {
        while(cash >= 1)
        {
            cash = cash - 1;
            (void) ++*one;
        }
    }

    printf("After all loops cash = %d\n", cash);
}

void getCoins(float change, int* quarter, int* dime, int* nickel, int* penny)
{
    // To find the correct change we need to turn the
    // current format of variable change (0.57) into
    // a easier to work with 57.
    int tenChange = change * 100;

    if(tenChange >= 25)
    {
        while(tenChange >= 25)
        {
            tenChange = tenChange - 25;
            (void) ++*quarter;
        }
    }

    if(tenChange >= 10)
    {
        while(tenChange >= 10)
        {
            tenChange = tenChange - 10;
            (void) ++*dime;
        }
    }

    if(tenChange >= 5)
    {
        while(tenChange >= 5)
        {
            tenChange = tenChange - 5;
            (void) ++*nickel;
        }
    }

    if(tenChange >= 1)
    {
        while(tenChange >= 1)
        {
            tenChange = tenChange - 1;
            (void) ++*penny;
        }
    }

    printf("After all loops change = %d\n", tenChange);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Create variables for the various things we create
    float c, m, dif, change;
    int cash, oneHundred, fifty, twenty, ten, five, one, quarter, dime, nickel,
        penny;

    printf("Enter the exact amount of the items (18.37): ");
    // Obtain the cost
    scanf("%f", &c);

    printf("Enter the amount of money given by the customer: ");
    // Obtain the money from customer
    scanf("%f", &m);

    // Obtain the difference of the cost
    // And the money given by calling the
    // getDif() function
    dif = getDif(c,m);

    // Send the difference to the getChange()
    // function, as well as the pointers 
    // cash & change which will be used in the
    // function and returned back here
    getChange(dif, &cash, &change);

    // First send the cash variable to the getCash
    // function along with pointers for each bill
    // The function will calculate the number of bills
    // to give to the customer and return each
    getCash(cash, &oneHundred, &fifty, &twenty, &ten, &five, &one);

    // Print the number of bills to give to the customer
    printf("Give the customer %d Hundred doller bill(s)!\n", oneHundred);
    printf("Give the customer %d Fifty doller bill(s)!\n", fifty);
    printf("Give the customer %d Twenty doller bill(s)!\n", twenty);
    printf("Give the customer %d Ten doller bill(s)!\n", ten);
    printf("Give the customer %d Five doller bill(s)!\n", five);
    printf("Give the customer %d One doller bill(s)!\n", one);
    
    // Second send the change variable to the getCoins
    // function along with pointers for each type of
    // coin. The function will calculate the number of
    // coins to give to the customer and return each
    getCoins(change, &quarter, &dime, &nickel, &penny);

    // Print the number of coins to give to the customer
    printf("Give the customer %d Quarter(s)\n", quarter);
    printf("Give the customer %d Dime(s)\n", dime);
    printf("Give the customer %d Nickel(s)\n", nickel);
    printf("Give the customer %d Penny(s)\n", penny);

    printf("%d\n", cash);
    printf("%.2f\n", change);
    printf("$%.2f\n", dif);
    return 0;
}
```

It is working ok, until I print out the number of Nickels, and Pennies to the customer. Instead of giving me a number which would make sense it is giving me a random string of numbers.

For example this is the output for these inputs:

> Enter the exact amount of the items (18.37): 123.32
>
> Enter the amount of money given by the customer: 124.00

```
Wow close to exact change! - No need for cash...
Give the customer 0 Hundred doller bill(s)!
...
Give the customer 0 One doller bill(s)!
After all loops change = 0
Give the customer 2 Quarter(s)
Give the customer 1 Dime(s)
Give the customer 32768 Nickel(s)
Give the customer 1596836443 Penny(s)
0
0.68
$0.68
```

Now if the program was working correctly, it should say:

- 2 Quarter(s)
- 1 Dime(s)
- 1 Nickel(s)
- 3 Penny(s)

But I'm getting those random(?) values. Could this be a problem with me not clearing my pointers? I have never worked with a language that uses them, and I have not learned enough to use them properly.

I tried to set all the cash variables (for example oneHundred) to NULL, but it gives me this compiler error:

```
change.c:204:14: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning
      to 'int' from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        oneHundred      = NULL;
                        ^ ~~~~
```

Any help would be amazing! I am just beginning to learn this language, and I hope this question will give me some insight on how to write better C in the future! Thank you!!

Comment: what is this `(void) ++*pointer;` for?

Comment: Just a suggesion, please refrain from using _single letter variable names._. makes so hard to read and co-relate the code.

Comment: I hadn't removed the (void) from when I was incorrectly using *pointer++; and getting the expression result unused error

Comment: @SouravGhosh I will refrain from using them from now on, Thank you! :)

Comment: Can someone explain why this is an off topic question? If it is I will understand, I just want to know for the future. Thank you

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Single-letter variable names can be okay in some cases (think `i`,`j`,`k` for iteration; or `x` and `y` for position), but I agree otherwise --- this is not one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to set them to `NULL` be cause they are not pointers, initialized them to `0` like this

```
cash = oneHundred = fifty = twenty = ten = five = one = quarter = dime = nickel = penny = 0;
```

`NULL` is used to initialized pointers to a special value, so you can test against it to check if the pointer is pointing somewhere or if it doesn't.

Comment: Ahh!! That fixed the problem!! Thank you so much! I guessed it was something to do with not initializing them to something else, but I was unsure how to do it. Also thank you for explaining it to me. Now I know! I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes!

Comment: I know this is pedantry, but I wouldn't say `NULL` is an *invalid* value (it's not UB to assign a pointer to NULL, or to check for NULL) --- I usually use the term "invalid" to mean uninitialized or dangling pointer. Though I'm not sure what *other* term one could use (apart from just "null pointer"), and I get your point.

Comment: Yes it was, and to be sure if you are on linux use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Comment: @TimČas I think of invalid, as a special value which you can use to check for `validity` it would be different to say `invalid pointer`. But I guess saying `special value` would be better.